# Condition for single bit code for a character in Huffman code?

Tags: math, compression, huffman-code

This is a question I ran into in school settings, but it keeps bugging me so I decided to ask it here.

In Huffman compression, fixed-length sequences (characters) are encoded with variable-length sequences. The code sequence length depends on the frequencies (or probabilities) of the source characters.

My questions is: what is the minimum highest character frequency, with which that character will be encoded by a single bit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is 0.4, that is, if the highest frequency *p* is *p >= 0.4*, 1-bit code for the corresponding character is guaranteed. In other words, this is a sufficient condition.

It is also true that p >= 1/3 is a necessary condition. That is, there may be examples where *0.4 > p >= 1/3*, and the shortest code is 1-bit, but there are no cases like that if *p < 1/3*.

The way to reason about that is to look at the way the code tree is constructed, in particular at the frequencies of the 3 last surviving subtrees. A proof appears in Johnsen, ["On the redundancy of binary Huffman codes", 1980](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/18/22757/01057240.pdf?arnumber=1057240) (unfortunately this is a paid link).

Comment: Except for the trivial binary case -- if there are only 2 symbols, Huffman always assigns 1 bit to each symbol, no matter what the frequencies are.

Comment: There's a proof of this included as an appendix in [this arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0508039.pdf).  Unfortunately, I can't follow the reasoning... I don't understand why it's necessarily true that the node labelled "u" was merged before the nodes labelled "v1" and "v2".

Answer (score 7):

In general, about 50% of the incoming symbol stream would have to consist of a given symbol for Huffman to code it as a single bit. The reason for this is that due to how Huffman coding works (the one symbol's encoding cannot be the prefix of another), by encoding a symbol with a single bit, you are requiring that the first bit for *every other symbol* be the opposite value (i.e. if one symbol is encoded as `0`, everything else must start with `1` plus at least one more bit). Since you're eliminating half of the possible encoding space for any given bit length, you need to be gaining a way to encode at least half of the symbols being input in order to break even.

Note that there is a special case where the symbol space only consists of 3 symbols. In such a case, whichever symbol has the greatest frequency will be encoded with 1 bit (since the other two will be the 2nd-bit variations of whichever first-bit value isn't chosen) - if 2 or more have equally greater probability, either one could be encoded. Thus, in the 3-symbol case it's possible that a symbol with, say, 34% probability could theoretically be coded as a single bit (say, `0`) while the other two might have 33% or lower probabilities and be coded as `10` and `11`.

So if you're considering *all* possibilities, then technically anything 1/3 or above could potentially be encoded as a single bit (in the 3-symbols case).

Comment: One exception is 3 symbols of equal probability: they can be encoded as 0, 10, 11

Comment: Yeah, I was already adding that in as a note. :) It's an edge case, but potentially relevant.

Comment: There are other, related cases (1/3, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6) but it's not true for all cases where one symbol has probability of 1/3. I'd love to see an answer that shows what the distinction is.

Comment: Thanks, Amber, but I am not sure you reasoning is correct.
For example, for 4 characters with frequencies (0.41, 0.2, 0.2, 0.19), I believe the encoding will (0, 10, 110, 111). This will give better compression than 4 two-bits characters, e.g. for 100 characters, 198 bits will be required instead of 200. However I am still not sure how to generalize this idea.

Comment: The reasoning is designed for general use cases, where the number of symbols is >>> 2^2, and thus most symbols will be encoded to more than 2-3 bits. For cases where the number of symbols is low, the "savings" from swapping from 2 to 1 bits for a character is relatively large even with lower frequencies, whereas for higher number of total symbols, the savings is lower unless the character occurs with a very high frequency. However, there is definitely a lower bound at 1/3 (except for the trivial case where the number of symbols is less than 3).

Comment: @Artelius - I believe [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.341.8687&rep=rep1&type=pdf) gives some reasoning as to why some but not all cases down to p=1/3 give single bit symbols, but it's going way over my head, so I can't summarize.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong. As @daphshez's answer correctly asserts, if there is some character with frequency greater than 2/5 then you are guaranteed that there will be some character that is encoded with a single bit. Furthermore, if all of the characters have frequency less than 1/3 then you are guaranteed that there are no characters encoded with a single bit. If neither of those conditions are met, it is non-trivial to determine whether some character will be encoded with a single bit without building the Huffman tree.